# Scala generic Class[_] parameter

Tags: scala, enums

I have the following class:

```
class MyClass[T <: Enum[T]](val clazz: Class[T]){
  def dummy = println(clazz.toString)
}
```

and the following method which is supposed to create `MyClass` objects:

```
def createMyClass(clazz: Class[_]) =
  if(clazz.isEnum)
    new MyClass(clazz) //compile error is here
  else throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"$clazz is not an enum")
```

But it refuses to compile. Actually, we pass the object of `Class[_]` which does not satisfy type bounds. Is there a way to tell the compiler that we have actually a `Class` representing a `Enum`.

In Java, I would just do casting, but I suppose Scala has some better way to deal with such things.

BTW,

```
new MyClass(clazz.asInstanceOf[Class[Enum[_]]])
```

does not work either

I cannot change methods' signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot change methods' signatures.

You *can* do it if necessary, using an existential type

```
def createMyClass(clazz: Class[_]) =
  if(clazz.isEnum)
    new MyClass(clazz.asInstanceOf[Class[T] forSome { type T <: Enum[T] }])
  else throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"$clazz is not an enum")
```

But you should carefully consider if it's actually necessary. `asInstanceOf` should be, if not always last resort, then close to it.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your method with same type constraints on `T` then it will compile

```
def createMyClass[T <: Enum[T]](clazz: Class[T]) =
  if(clazz.isEnum) new MyClass(clazz) 
  else throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"$clazz is not an enum")
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> class MyClass[T <: Enum[T]](val clazz: Class[T]){
    def dummy = println(clazz.toString)
  }
defined class MyClass

scala> def createMyClass[T <: Enum[T]](clazz: Class[T]) =
    if(clazz.isEnum)
      new MyClass(clazz) else throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"$clazz is not an enum")
defined function createMyClass
```